# In Reactjs how to insert api data into ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Reactjs currently I'm working on antdesign table I want to fetch a data from external API and insert data into table but it give me error I also also google it but nothing found please help me
below is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Table } from "antd";

function App() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState({});
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
    );

    setstate(res.data);
    setloading(false);
  };
  const data = loading
    ? "wait"
    : state.map(row => ({ Name: row.name, Email: row.email }));

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "Name",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      title: "Email",
      dataIndex: "Email",
      width: 150
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        pagination={{ pageSize: 50 }}
        scroll={{ y: 240 }}
      />
      ,
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-tdd-7zxhw)

Comment: Can you please include the error as well? Thanks!

Comment: Data is 'wait' while it is loading. replace 'wait' with [] and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<Table />` components data prop might be a array like data structure you sending it an string, when you assigning `"wait"` to `data` props and you might get an error for that, instead you can use something like below:

```
const data = loading
    ? [] 
    : state.map(row => ({ Name: row.name, Email: row.email }));
```

in which we assign an empty array to data while it is being in loading state, **also you should store your api data in your state, not as a variable inside of your function, what you are doing there is an obvious bad practice!**

Answer (score 5):

in addition to the accepted answer, note in the following snippet the conditional rendering also how to use `state`, `setState` functions,I suggest to check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) on how to use react hooks:

here is a better implementation of your code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Table } from "antd";

function App() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    await Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then(
      res => {
        setloading(false);
        setstate(
          res.data.map(row => ({
            Name: row.name,
            Email: row.email,
            id: row.id
          }))
        );
      }
    );
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "Name",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      title: "Email",
      dataIndex: "Email",
      width: 150
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        "Loading"
      ) : (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={state}
          pagination={{ pageSize: 50 }}
          scroll={{ y: 240 }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-wind-400du)

Comment: Just to note if you have multiple data items you should do this: `res.data.map((row, index) => ({key: index,Name: row.name,Email: row.email,id: row.id}))`